# SwiftUI Text iOS15: Email or URL inside Text view render using accent color

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-text, ios15

When running the following code in iOS15, the color of a URL or email address within the contents uses the accent color instead of the foreground color. How can I override that?

```swift
Text("Send a message to john@email.com to request support")
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
```

[image: How Text view is rendered in iOS15]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use [`Text(verbatim:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(verbatim:)) to render the string as-is, and not automatically create a link from the email.

```
Text(verbatim: "Send a message to john@email.com to request support")
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
```

Result:

[image: Text is all blue]

You can also set your own accent color, if you want.

```
Text("Send a message to john@email.com to request support")
    .tint(.green)
```

Result:

[image: Email is green, rest of text is black]